# Cosmos Db - search on value from array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using a query for Cosmos, how do I select out all Roles that have an ID of '11'?

```
{
   "Roles":[
      {
         "Name":"Admin",
         "ID":[
            "11",
            "22",
            "33"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"User",
         "ID":[
            "11"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I think it sort of looks like this but not sure about the where clause...

```
select value r from c join r in c.Roles join i in r.ID // where i = ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
select value r from c join r in c.Roles where ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.ID,'11',false)
```

Hope this can help you:).